# Disable introspection feature for Magento 2 GraphQL

Tags: graphql, magento2

The application I'm using has the GraphQL Introspection feature enabled. While the testing team did not identify any sensitive or “hidden” information within the GraphQL schema, there is a potential for sensitive information disclosure through this feature with future releases of the application.
How do Disable this feature ?

Using AEM and Magento

Answer (score 1):

To disable introspection, add this config to app/etc/env.php file in Magento:

```
'graphql' => [
    'disable_introspection' => true,
]
```

More information: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/usage/introspection-queries/